# How to inject jQuery using Chrome Extention with Manifest V3

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to run some jQuery code from Content Script but some website doesn't include jQuery, is there any way to inject it?
I tried this but it seem doesn't work at all

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes.

> If you want to access jquery before body then instead of "document_end" use  "document_start" in manifest.json file.

### Answer 1.

include it before your content script in manifest.json.

1. download jquery version that you want to use.
2. specify it in manifest.json

manifest.json

```html
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<tab_url_pattern>"],
      "run_at": "document_end", 
      "js": ["jquery3.5.1.min.js", "contentScript.js"],
      "all_frames": false
    },
  ]
}
```

### Answer 2.

expose jquery file using "Web_accessible_resource" and inject it in required tab using document.body.appendChild()

```html
{
  "manifest_version":3,
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "content_scripts":[{
      "matches": ["<url_pattern_1>"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "all_frames": false
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "otherJquery.js"],
      "matches": ["<url_pattern_1>"]
    }
  ]
}
```

in contentScript.js

```html
const contentScriptLinks = ['jquery-1.11.3.min.js', 'otherJquery.js'];

contentScriptLinks.forEach(src => {
  let el = document.createElement('script');
  el.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(src);
  document.body.appendChild(el);
});
```

Comment: Should the same approach work with popup within popup.js loaded from the popup.html?  I'm getting error `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'".Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: Yes, it should work. But, if we include any inline javascript in html file like `onClick=doSomethingHandler()" or any other inline javascript in popup.html. It will give this error.